# Como validar o valor selecionado na dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

Estou usando o CompareValidator para verificar se o valor selecionado na dropdownlist é "Selecione", mais não esta funcionado, segue o código.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIdPisSt" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsIdPisSt" DataTextField="Descricao"  
    DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="790px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Selecione</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>                 
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlIdPisSt" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage=" * " Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="" ForeColor = "Red">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

O que eu estou fazendo de erro.
Alguém pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, tenta usar o RequiredValidator, pois o "Selecione" não contem valor e o RequiredValidator vai pegar.

Tenta e fala para gente se deu certo.

Comment: Valeu a dica, RBoschini, para usar o RequiredValidator, foi só adicionar a propriedade InitialValue=" " que solucionou meu problema. Obrigado.

Comment: Da um joinha ai que eu ganho ponto! ;)
Por favor!!! :D

Comment: +1 Eu dei um joinha só por conta da mendicância sua. hahahaa Excelente resposta btw

Comment: mendicância virtual, so nao passo a agencia e conta por vergonha mesmo. 
:p